# How can I disable jsplumb dragaable for a specific node on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb and I'm firing summer-note on double click on the text inside node, what I want is to disable dragging of the node when my summer-note jQuery executes. I searched over Google but was unable to find that how I can disable drag-gable for the node I clicked on click.
Here is what I have tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  window.is_summerNote = false;
  $(".terminator-title, .node-title, .diamond-title, .note-title ").on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.detail > 1) {
      if ($(window.node))
        $(window.node).summernote('destroy');
      window.is_summerNote = true;

      window.node = this;
      window.id = $(this).parent().attr("id")
      jsPlumb.draggable("#dragcodes", {
      drag: function (event, ui) { //gets called on every drag
      //Dont Know what to do here to stop dragging for that node
      }
     });
      $(this).summernote('focus');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can anybody help me out with this please?

Comment: Could you add the html markup? (a basic example would be fine). That would make it easier to understand the context of the javaScript

Comment: i didnt get you @admcfajn

Comment: @admcfajn just want to know how i can this jsPlumb.draggable("#dragcodes", {
      drag: function (event, ui) { //gets called on every drag
      //Dont Know what to do here to stop dragging for that node
      }  in ma js file